# PHP: How to create a linear function, calculating a credit card fee?

Tags: php, math

I'm working on a PHP project for a customer who has to receive credit card payments.

Most merchants offer an fixed pricing of 2.9% + 2.25 DKK. Right now, I'm able to calculate my fee using;

```
$price = 10;
$fee = ($price*0.029)+2.25;
// $fee = 2.54
```

So, as of now, the visitor will pay 12.54 DKK, but of course there will be added fees to my inserted "user-pays-fees", and my customer would still have to pay 2.61366 DKK for the transaction, leaving 9.92634 DKK for withdrawal, instead of pure 10 DKK.

Inserting the formula in e.g. GeoGebra, it is `y = 1.029x + 2.25`, if that is any help? The Y-axis represents how much the visitor is charged, and the X-axis represents how much is withdrawable.

So, my question is: How do I formulate a linear function that calculates backwards and defines `$price` from what should be withdrawable (with PHP)?

Comment: that's basic algebra. you've got `y= stuff with x`. reverse it and have `x = stuff with y`.

Comment: @MarcB I updated the question as you wrote your comment, and I know the linear algebra formular, `y = 1.029x + 2.25`, but I'm not sure how to reverse it? And how to insert it into a PHP-script?

Comment: like I said. it's basic algebra. write it out on paper, and solve for X instead of Y.

Comment: @MarcB Well, I obviosly can't figure it out myself. Could you might point me a little further, in the right direction ;)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a simple math question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got what you want, so think in this way:

1. you have original price
2. you want to calculate final transferAmount

that:

```
transferAmount = originalPrice + fee
```

but fee here depends on transferAmount

```
fee = transferAmount * 0.029 + 2.25
```

now solve it:

```
transferAmount = originalPrice + transferAmount * 0.029 + 2.25
transferAmount*(1-0.029) = originalPrice + 2.25
transferAmount = (originalPrice + 2.25) / (1-0.029)
```

in php:

```
$price = 10;
$total = ($price + 2.25) / (1.0 - 0.029); // 12.615859938208033
$fee = $total - $price; // 2.6158599382080325
```

now you can verify:

```
12.615... * 0.029 + 2.25 = 2.615...
```

ie, merchant will take `2.615...` as fee and result is `10`

Comment: That is exactly the code I listed above. Your code doesn't keep in mind, that there will be added fees on top of `$totalprice`

Comment: @JonathanBredoChristensen what is added fees? how they are calculated?

Comment: As described in my question, they are substracted from the transfered amount, leaving a little less withdrawable. The fees are 2.9% + 2.25

Comment: @JonathanBredoChristensen finally got you

Comment: Sorry, @Lashane, but it's still not the answer. The merchant will still collect a fee on top of the defined fee, why the formular should go backwards. Basically, your code is the exact same as mine.

Comment: @JonathanBredoChristensen no, `$total` will be 2.615859 with updated formula, and merchant will subtract 2.615, so your customer finally get 10.0 as expected

Comment: Sorry, I misread your code - it works perfect now!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that given fee=2.59, you want the base price?

In this case, you could do:

```
$feeMinusTax = $fee-2.25;
$originalPrice = $feeMinusTax/0.029;
```