# Math problem: calculate price to pay taking into consideration the payment processor fees

Tags: math, paypal

I'm struggling in finding the right formula to add the right amount to the product cost, so when payment is completed and fees are taken by PayPal, the amount received is exactly the product price.

It must be calculated using a formula because prices are taken through API calls from our supplier. The prices may vary if the supplier changes them, so they can't be hardcoded and result in a loss after the transaction fees.

Let's make an example. I have a product which costs 3.76€. PayPal takes 3.4% + 0.35€ for the transaction. If i just do the following `3.76 + ((3.76 * 0.034) + 0.35)` it will result in a loss, because then the fee will be calculated on that price, which is greater, therefore the fee is greater. We will receive less than 3.76€.

So how I can calculate the price to charge to receive exactly 3.76€?

**EDIT 1**

For who is interested about the answer in code "format", while I was researching about the first answer I've got here, I found this question on stackoverflow, sadly closed even if very useful for probably many people: [PHP: How to create a linear function, calculating a credit card fee?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30111908/php-how-to-create-a-linear-function-calculating-a-credit-card-fee)

If you look at the first answer you'll find the PHP code.

Comment: Note that PayPal's User Agreement has a "no surcharges" clause, so whatever total price you are calculating has to be the same total price used with any other payment method (credit cards, checks, cash, other processors, etc)

Comment: I know about that, but as how our system works (monthly subscription and then our users can buy the products at exact same price as we buy them from supplier), we can't comply with that with PayPal. If we pay X price at the supplier we can't get less than X. Who wants to really use PayPal should agree with this, or use our other free methods. It's just a comfort method for some users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work backwards from the price you want to get. You need to solve for X so that after taking 0.35 EUR and 3.4% you'll be left with the price you want:

```
X * (1 - 0.034) - 0.35 = 3.76
X * 0.966 - 0.35 = 3.76
x * 0.966 = 4.11
X = 4.2547 (note: this is rounded to four decimal places)
```

If you charge 4.26 (ceiling the result of the calculation), you'll be left with (4.26 - 0.034 * 4.26 - 0.35) = 3.76516, so either 3.76 or 3.77, depending on how PayPal handles the rounding.